# How can I store JSON response from httprequest into a json file and validate json data against UI field values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, protractor, cucumber

How can I store JSON response from httprequest into a json file and validate json data against UI field values in Protractor Cucumber F/w using Javascript.

Sample HttpRequest URL: https://chercher.tech/sample/api/product/read

I need to save the http response into **json**/text file and need to validate each value against **table on UI** usining Javascript. I am using **Protractor Cucumber POM framework** (Javascript)

Comment: Why have you asked the same thing three times in one question, the title, the first sentence and the last sentence are all the same thing - perhaps rather than repeating yourself, you could add a little about what you've tried, what your research has found so far, an example of your code etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe JSON.parse() will help you. You can use it to create object basing on the JSON, then you can use this object as you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Please don't use, recommend or link to w3schools.

Comment: @"Chris G", why is w3schools not recommended?

Comment: I have changed the link